# Javascript function which polls an async endpoint and inserts the result in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, json, asynchronous, dom

I read about debounce this morning and ended up needing something similar to the concept in real life this evening to build a poll that checks whether a link I receive from an async call is ready to be used in a href element.

But what I'm asking for are

- highlights of the risk to my implementation,
- to learn if there are standard polling patterns for this use case, and
- how to refactor my implementation into any of these standard patterns.

After numerous iterations here's the code that worked

```js
    const handler = async () => {
      document.querySelector('#trello-board-link').style.display = 'none';
      document.querySelector('#trello-board-link-loader').style.display = 'block';

      let link = await getLink();
      let intervalId;
       /**
       * I initially used a while loop which blocked,
       * and then refactored to use setInterval. I can't
       * think of anything wrong with this as it is now, but is this risky or wrong in
       * an actual production environment?
       **/
      if (link === undefined) {
        intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
          link = await getLink();
          if (link) {
            document.querySelector('#trello-board-link').href = link;

            document.querySelector('#trello-board-link').style.display = 'block';
            document.querySelector('#trello-board-link-loader').style.display = 'none';
            clearInterval(intervalId);
          }
        }, 500);
      } else {
        document.querySelector('#trello-board-link').href = link;

        document.querySelector('#trello-board-link').style.display = 'block';
        document.querySelector('#trello-board-link-loader').style.display = 'none';
      }
    };

    /**
     * This is only here in case the href elements haven't loaded, but please what's a 
     * standard way to check if an element exists before accessing it? Right now I'm only
     * checking if the Document has loaded, but not sure if this guarantees all elements  
     * have loaded.
    **/
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler);
```

getLink is simply an async function that returns the resolved value of a promise

```js
    const getLink = async () => {
      const res = await fetch(`some url`);
      const result = await res.json();
    
      link = result && result.member && result.member.metaData && result.member.metaData.trelloBoardUrl; 

      return link;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

> highlights of the risk to my implementation

If due to server error, the link never gets created at any instance then the  `setInterval` schedule will run indefinitely. You should implement a timeout as a check for such cases.

> to learn if there are standard polling patterns for this use case, and

If you can do without polling, then do without it. Assuming you can influence how the endpoint is implemented, then you should consider using web socket for it. Web socket will give more simplicity to your front end and likely offer even better performance for your overall system - no wasted resource for checking unready link on both ends.